# Add rewrite rule for site login to .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess-configuration

I have been trying to add rewrite rule to .htaccess file but it does not seem to work. I have Joomla latest version and I am trying to do it by:

```
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule index.php/en?option=com_users&amp;view=login [F]
```

So I paste it here:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule index.php/en?option=com_users&amp;view=login [F]

## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site then comment out the operations listed 
# below by adding a # to the beginning of the line.
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` on Joomla!
#
# Block any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root home page
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
```

What is possibly wrong?

Comment: You don't seem to have a RewriteCond statement so the system probably doesn't know what rule you want to Rewrite. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to disable access to frontend login page. Once user will try to paste to his browser it will redirect to frontpage  `index.php/en?option=com_users&amp;view=login`

Comment: As this is not specifically a Joomla issue you might find more information and examples over at https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bhtaccess%5D+redirect

Comment: Or you can try this search which has various ideas of how to do it, including the one you have shown here. https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=joomla+disable+front+end+login+screen